# df with a columns of dates add a duration column between current and next row's date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

suppose I have a df of dates:

```
date          quantity
2015-01-01    100
2016-01-01    500
2016-01-05    100
```

and I want to add another new column about the time between current row's date and next row's date. If last row, refer to today's date.

```
date          quantity    days
2015-01-01    100         365
2016-01-01    500         4
2016-01-05    100         1227
```

Note that: 1227 is the number of days from 2016-01-05 to 2019-05-16 (today).
I can do it with loops, just wonder if I can make use of pandas to do it cleanly.

Comment: `df.date.diff().shift(-1).fillna(pd.datetime.now().date() - df.date.iloc[-1].date())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we push it into one-line

```
df['New']=df.date.append(pd.Series(pd.datetime.now())).diff().dropna().dt.days.values
df
Out[102]: 
        date  quantity   New
0 2015-01-01       100   365
1 2016-01-01       500     4
2 2016-01-05       100  1226
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shift and use the dt accessor on the result:

```
In [11]: df.date - df.date.shift()
Out[11]:
0        NaT
1   365 days
2     4 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [12]: (df.date - df.date.shift()).dt.days
Out[12]:
0      NaN
1    365.0
2      4.0
Name: date, dtype: float64

In [13]: (df.date - df.date.shift()).dt.days.fillna(0)
Out[13]:
0      0.0
1    365.0
2      4.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

---

shift upwards to get the same result you desired:

```
In [14]: (df.date.shift(-1) - df.date).dt.days.fillna(0)
Out[14]:
0    365.0
1      4.0
2      0.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

---

As commented you can do this cleaner using diff:

```
In [21]: -df.date.diff(-1).fillna(0)
Out[21]:
0   365 days
1     4 days
2     0 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

In [22]: -df.date.diff(-1).fillna(0).dt.days
Out[22]:
0    365
1      4
2      0
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Find difference and fillna,

```
df.loc[:, 'diff'] = np.abs(df.date-df.date.shift(-1)).dt.days
df['diff'] = df['diff'].fillna(np.abs(df.date-pd.Timestamp.now()).dt.days)



    date        quantity    diff
0   2015-01-01  100         365.0
1   2016-01-01  500         4.0
2   2016-01-05  100         1226.0
```